# Add string depending on counter length?

Tags: javascript

I have a assignment where I write a number in Expanded Form and display it as a string.

For example:

```
expandedForm(7020); // should return '7000 + 20';
expandedForm(7402); // '7000 + 400 + 2';
```

I haven't figured out all of it yet, but my current code looks like:

```
function expandedForm(num) {

  let numArr = Array.from(num.toString()).map(Number),
      counter = numArr.length,
      answer = "";

  for(let i = 0; i < numArr.length; i++) {
      (numArr[i] === 0) ? counter-- : --counter;
      console.log(numArr[i].toString(), counter);       
  }

}

expandedForm(702); // returns '7' 2 and '2' 0
```

I skip 0 since it's supposed to be ignored, go through each integer and check the amount of units it has with the counter. This is helpful but now I'm trying to somehow add '00' to the '7' based on `counter` value. So if `counter` is 2 I need to add two 0 as a string '00'.

There is a good chance I'm not doing this with best practices so if something should be done differently with what I already have please suggest. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd (study the documentation please!!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  "0".repeat(counter)
```

thats it... then just concatenate all those to strings and you are done :)

---

Also note that:

```
 (numArr[i] === 0) ? counter-- : --counter;
```

basically equals `counter--;`.

---

"best practice" is quite opinion based, heres how I'd do that:

```
  const chars = [...("" + input)];
  return chars
     .map((char, i) => char + "0".repeat(chars.length - i - 1))
     .filter(it => it[0] !== "0")
     .join(" + ");
```

Comment: it would be great if you post a full solution for the benefits of everybody, thanks.

Comment: Wow .. that couldn't have been easier. Answered my question and completed my assignment, thank you sir :0

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with ternary operator statement? Because if argument has 0 I need to skip that .. ?

Comment: But ... you don't skip anything. If its 0 you do `counter--`, if its another digit you do `--counter`. Both will decrease counter.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in code golfing (it's fun, but not always a "best practice"), you can use:

```
[...`${input}`].map((c,i,a)=>c.padEnd(a.length-i,'0')).filter(c=>+c).join(' + ')
```

Here it is in action:

```
> input = 2
> [...`${input}`].map((c,i,a)=>c.padEnd(a.length-i,'0')).filter(c=>+c).join(' + ')
'2'
> input = 200
> [...`${input}`].map((c,i,a)=>c.padEnd(a.length-i,'0')).filter(c=>+c).join(' + ')
'200'
> input = 209777800001
> [...`${input}`].map((c,i,a)=>c.padEnd(a.length-i,'0')).filter(c=>+c).join(' + ')
'200000000000 + 9000000000 + 700000000 + 70000000 + 7000000 + 800000 + 1'
```

Here is how it works:

```
[...`${input}`]
```

makes an array out of the digits in your number. For example, 7503 becomes `['7', '5', '0', '3']`

```
.map((c,i,a)=>c.padEnd(a.length-i,'0'))
```

maps each digit to its padding with the correct number of zeros. The callback to `map` takes the digit, the array index, and then the array itself. This gives us, for the running example, `['7000', '500', '00', '3']`

```
.filter(c=>+c)
```

removes any string of zeros such as `"0"`, `"0000"`, etc. from the array. Now we have `['7000', '500', '3']`

```
.join(' + ')
```

does what it looks like it does.

Here's what this solution does not do:

1. Handle the value 0 (because you get an empty string)
2. Handle negative numbers
3. Handle non integers

The first one can be fixed by doing

```
[...`${input}`].map((c,i,a)=>c.padEnd(a.length-i,'0')).filter(c=>+c).join(' + ') || '0'
```

Since this is an assignment, I'll leave the other two cases to you.

Also have fun explaining this to the person that assigned you the problem. ;-)

As mentioned in another answer, best practice is subjective. You can be more explicit by introducing intermediate variables:

```
const chars = Array.from(`${input}`);
const places = chars.map((c, i, a) => c.padEnd(a.length - i, '0'));
const nonZeros = places.filter(c => Number(c) !== 0);
const result = nonZeros.join(' + ') || '0';
```

Again, best practices would also require you do some error handling. What if your input is NaN or a string, array, or object? What if it is infinity? Floating point?